# Orthographe du prénom « George »

Tags: orthographe, noms-propres, évolution, prénoms

Je suis intrigué par l'introduction du **s** à la fin du nom « George ». En effet, dans tous les écrits antérieurs à 1850 environ, « George » s'écrit en français exactement comme en anglais (c'est plutôt, d'ailleurs, qu'il s'écrit en anglais  exactement comme en français). Dans le célèbre dictionnaire Moreri de 1732, par exemple, on ne trouve jamais de **s** au nom « George ».

Puis soudain, vers le milieu du XIXe siècle, un **s** apparaît à la fin de ce nom ! Je cherche donc à savoir qui a introduit cette modification, par quelle magie des circonstances elle a réussi à s'imposer, et quel sens profond cache l'introduction tardive de cette lettre phonétiquement inutile ?

Je serais donc très reconnaissant envers toute personne qui pourrait me fournir la moindre information sur cette question, beaucoup moins anodine qu'elle ne semble à première vue.

Comment: Bonjour
Moi j'ai toujours su (je ne me souviens depuis quand) que le "s" a la fin de GEORGES servait à distinguer les filles des garçons.
George fille sans "s"
Georges garçon avec "s"
Est-ce exact ou non ??
Merci de vos précisions.

Answer (score 8):

Le postulat exprimé dans la question est inexact. La graphie George**s** est bien antérieure à 1850 et il n'y a pas eu de changement « magique » ou brutal de l'orthographe du nom Georges.

Une recherche sur des livres imprimés autour de 1650, deux siècles auparavant donc, permet de constater que les deux variantes coexistent déjà, parfois dans le même ouvrage et pour désigner la même personne, comme les deux exemples suivants le montrent.

[Lettres du Chevalier Georges à Monseigneur le Prince de Condé](https://books.google.fr/books?id=UStRa6Tk-MgC&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)

[image]
[image]

La même orthographe est reprise dans le titre de l'ouvrage qui fait suite à ce dernier, ce qui démontre que cette orthographe ne choquait personne.

[image]

[Le Parlement de Bourgo[n]gne, son origine, son établissement et son progrès](https://books.google.fr/books?id=mZBFAAAAcAAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr#v=onepage&q&f=false)

[image]
[image]

Plus ancien encore, un [manuscrit de 1478](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/btv1b9009496c) où est écrit *George**s** Delachambre* :
[image]

Pour ce qui est de l'origine de ce *s* final, @NathanCoustenoble en a donné [l'explication](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/18937/1109) dans sa réponse. Il s'agit de la persistance de la terminaison du cas sujet, que l'on retrouve dans d'autres prénoms comme Charles, Gilles, Hugues, Jacques/James, Jules et Yves, confirmée [ici](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=george&T3.x=0&T3.y=0)  et [là](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles#.C3.89tymologie)

Comment: Bien documenté.... +1 ;)

Answer (score 5):

En français médiéval, un nom pouvait être sous forme sujet ou sous forme régime. Au singulier, le **cas sujet** de George s'écrivait avec un 's', mais pas au **cas régime**.

De nos jours, les anglais ont gardé le cas régime et nous le cas sujet.

Pour la réponse à pourquoi le changement ne s'est effectué qu'au XIX°, je ne peux rien affirmer, mais c'est à cette époque - entre le 17° et le 19°, que le *français tend à s'uniformiser* et à évincer les nombreux dialectes présents. Il est fort possible que ce soit à cette époque que l'orthographe de Georges a été définie, mettant ainsi fin au débat. Après ce n'est qu'une supposition de ma part...

[Pour plus d'informations sur les cas !](http://ancien-francais.blogspot.fr/2011/11/les-cas.html?m=1)

Comment: Merci pour cette précision, mais je dois avouer mon ignorance de ce que sont les cas "sujet" et "régime".: pourriez-vous m'en dire plus ?

Comment: La disparition des cas en français est il me semble bien plus ancienne que les dates citées, mais c'est une bonne piste.

Comment: Edit : Voir la réponse de @jlliagre ?

Answer (score 2):

D'après le [wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Georges) :

> Du latin Georgius emprunté au grec ancien Γεώργιος, Geốrgios, dérivé de γεωργός, geôrgós, formé de γῆ gễ (« terre ») et ἔργον érgon (« travail »), littéralement « celui qui travaille à la terre ».

Il semble donc que le **s** final vient de l’étymologie. Beaucoup de langues  l'ont supprimé mais le français l'a conservé, voir la même page du wiktionnaire

Comment: Pas que les anglais, espagnol  *Jorge*, italien *Giorgio*.

Comment: @Laure: Effectivement je n'ai pas pensé aux autres langues.

Comment: Objection: le Français n'a pas _conservé_ le "s", mais il l'a **institué tardivement**, même si ce "s" fait partie de la forme grecque d'origine. La forme dite anglaise est en réalité reprise du français, comme _Rome_, _Cologne_ ou  _Munich_, par exemple: Je n'ai jamais rencontré la forme en "s" dans les manuscrits ou les imprimés antérieurs au XIXe siècle.

Answer (score 0):

Toutes les sources paraissent s'accorder sur le fait que:

- George (sans s) est l'usage anglais
- Georges (avec le s) est l'usage français

Après, dans tous les pays, il est possible de varier.

L'origine est toujours la même, le grec: *qui laboure le sol*.

Comment: Γεώργος qui a donné le latin Georgius - le  son /s/  est présent dans la racine.

Answer (score 0):

A jiliagre:

Merci pour cet apport très intéressant qui m'aide à corriger ma démarche, car je n'avais sincèrement pas rencontré d'occurrence en "s" avant 1877. Le fait est que je n'avais recherché que sur les pages de couverture. Votre contribution m'a donc incité à approfondir la recherche.

J'ai ainsi effectué une recherche dans le texte du dictionnaire Moreri (éd. 1759), au tome 5 (contenant l'entrée *George*) : Gallica renvoie 254 occurrences de *George*, dont 33(!) contiennent le "s", soit un rapport de 13% (donc 87% sans "s"). Il semble donc que l'usage du "s" soit ancien, en effet, comme vous l'avez montré, mais soit toujours demeuré très minoritaire jusqu'à la fin du XIXe siècle. Au reste, s'agissant du saint martyr, initiateur du nom, Moreri le donne sans "s".

Peut-être faut-il voir dans ce "s" occasionnel une certaine pédanterie à vouloir souligner sa connaissance de l'étymologie, et cette pédanterie serait néanmoins une marque d'ignorance, puisqu'il semble bien que la vraie forme francisée n'ait pas de "s", tant sa supériorité numérique est écrasante avant 1900, et sa reprise en langue anglaise témoigne qu'elle est bien la forme originale. Cette hypothèse de pédanterie maladroite est à rapprocher de ce que certaines personnes, soucieuses de bien parler, se sentent obligées d'appliquer le subjonctif dès qu'elles emploient le relatif "que", ce qui est parfois une erreur flagrante...

Il reste toujours à expliquer comment une forme restée très minoritaire pendant des siècles soit soudain devenue universelle.

Comment: Même si le s final a probablement cessé d'être prononcé au moyen-âge, un manuscrit du XIIIe contient par exemple «  La vie et li martires monseigneur seint Jorge », accuser de pédanterie et d'ignorance les personnes mettant un *s* à Georges est un anachronisme, voire un contresens. L'orthographe de nombreux mots et noms n'était pas figée à cette époque et les différences observées ne choquaient pas les lecteurs. La présence de lettres sans rapport avec la prononciation mais justifiées par l'étymologie est d'ailleurs au contraire une caractéristique récurrente du français.

Comment: Soit, mais il s'agit néanmoins d'un usage statistiquement marginal, et je cherche juste à savoir pourquoi l'usage marginal est devenu l'usage général, au point qu'en Français, l'usage sans "s" a disparu alors qu'il était le plus généralement employé. La pédanterie n'est qu'une hypothèse, je n'affirme pas qu'il s'agit de la raison véritable, je cherche seulement...

Comment: Minoritaire je veux bien, encore que ça n'ait pas toujours été le cas d'après ngrams, mais marginal, certainement pas : https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=georges,george&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cgeorges%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BGeorges%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGEORGES%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cgeorge%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BGeorge%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGEORGE%3B%2Cc0t4;,georges;,c0;,s0;;Georges;,c0;;GEORGES;,c0;.t4;,george;,c0;,s0;;George;,c0;;GEORGE;,c0